# How to construct package URI using PackageManager in android

Tags: android, android-package-managers

I need to construct PackageUri in order to uninstall package using action.delete. I obtained PackageInfo object using PackageMananger. Is there any way to construct PackageUri using PackageInfo?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it, lets say we have PackageInfo pinfo

```
String pkg= "package:"+ pinfo.packageName;
Uri pkg_uri= Uri.parse(pkg);
```

Now we have package uri, to uninstall

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE, pkg_uri);
startActivity(intent);
```